# SQL select firstname from id

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with this. 
I have these 2 tables. I need to print the firstname from the corresponding id. It's for something like a buddy app where people get matched so for example i need it to print 'Charlotte and Sam are now buddies'.

users:

```
    id  /  firstname  /  lastname    
--------/-------------/------------
     1  /  charlotte  /  jeuris
     2  /  sam        /  verdaet
     3  /  hilde      /  hayen
```

matched:

```
  user1  /  user2
---------/----------
   2     /    3
   1     /    3
```

what i have now is:

```
  $statement = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT users.id 
    FROM users 
    LEFT JOIN matched ON users.id=matched.user1 
    and LEFT JOIN matched ON users.id=matched.user2");
```

but at this point i really don't have a clue anymore what's wrong or right..

Thanks!

Comment: You don't put `AND` between joins.

Answer (score 0):

You don't join `matched` twice, you join `users` twice, since you want to get two names from one row of `matched`.

```
SELECT u1.firstname AS friend1, u2.firstname AS friend2
FROM matched AS m
JOIN users AS u1 ON u1.id = m.user1
JOIN users AS u2 ON u2.id = m.user2
```

And you don't need to use `LEFT JOIN`, since you can't have matches between nonexistent users.

Comment: okay i get it i guess, thanks! the only problem i have now is that i don't exactly know how to print it on my index page, with echo i think? But not sure what has to go after the echo

Comment: `echo "{$row['friend1']} is friends with {$row['friend2']}<br>";`